# Formik validateForm().then(..) does not set 'errors' correctly

Tags: reactjs, formik

Does anyone know why after calling Formik's `validateForm` manually, per the [docs](https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#manually-triggering-validation), the `errors` object inside the `then` does **not** contain any appropriate errors, but is incorrectly blank, `{}`? Is something not firing?

I have the Yup schema defined and it works correctly automatically with the Submit control. With this custom Button control, I want to handle it manually.

```
<Button type="button" disabled={isSubmitting} 
        onClick={() => {
            validateForm().then(() => {
                // At this point, 'errors' is empty {} when it should NOT be!
                if ('startDate' in errors || 'expirationDate' in errors) {
                    // etc.
                }    
            });
```

I created a similar thread on their [GitHub](https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/3361).

Their example:

```
       <button
         type="button"
         onClick={() => validateForm().then(() => console.log('blah'))}
```

Comment: `.then` indicates async and  `errors` is not passed into the callback, so it would appear to be a stale closure.

Comment: Thanks, so should I pass `errors` somewhere? Could you show a quick example?

Comment: I've never used Formik, but it appears from [their docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#validateform-values-any--promiseformikerrorsvalues) that the `.then` will accept the errors object.

Comment: Yes you're right thanks just verified it!